# Should we need to add explicit db migrations when using MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Recently I have faced issue with EF codefirst DB migrations. We have used MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion for DB initializer.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TestDataContext, MyConfiguration>());

internal sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TestDataContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
...
```

Issue is that - we accidentally ran old DB migration file using the below command :

```
Update-database -TargetMigration some_old_test_migration_cs_file
```

This caused us to loose latest entity schema changes and we were unable to push latest changes   to database. After wasting a lot of time in troubleshoot, we fixed that issue by deleting migration history from the table `__MigrationHistory`.

My question is - Should we also add migration scripts whenever entity (code level) changes though we have enabled the automatic migrations?

What would be the best practice around this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Automatic Migrations, you shouldn't need to code any explicit migrations yourself. Entity Framework will automatically update the database to match the current state of your entities when you create a context.

Comment: What about the production system. Is it good practice to have AutomaticMigrations on? If yes, what about data loss?

Comment: It depends on your system. It's best practice to have tested the application thoroughly to make sure your database migrations don't cause problems, but after that if nothing else is expecting the database to be a certain way then migrations just automate a step that could go wrong if done manually, so I see no problem with using them in production. As for data loss, if you don't want that then set `AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;` and find a way to migrate data when your changes can't be automatically migrated without data changes.